# Weinre breaks window.sessionStorage.setItem

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, session-storage, weinre

Ran into a weird one now.

On FireFox 30.0,when I include [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html) in my html 5 page (for a hybrid mobile application), `window.sessionStorage.setItem` is suddenly not a function any more (or does not exists or something).

Remove weinre script, and all is fine again.

In the actual Android web container on the mobile device, it seems fine again.

So, not a train smash, but very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to [create an issue on Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssueDetails!init.jspa?pid=12312420&components=12316604&issuetype=1), if this is still a problem.

I'd be happy to do that for you, but would like to have a better description of the problem; was an error thrown when you tried to access `sessionStorage`?  Or did it happen even though you never tried to access `sessionStorage`?

Comment: Hi - I am not sure if this issue is still relevant, have not used sessionStorage recently. Be that as it may, the issue is that when weinre was included, `window.sessionStorage.setItem` was undefined. Remove weinre, and it's fine. I would hold of logging a JIRA issue,since I can't give you proper issue duplication details at present (beyond the description as above). Thanks for the response though ;)

Comment: Thanks; do you happen to remember if you were accessing sessionStorage at all?  It could be that while weinre was trying to wrap it with it's hooks, it turns out it wasn't defined for your platform, or perhaps was not accessible in the way weinre was accessing it, so just the process of trying to wrap it caused the exception.

Comment: Hi Patrick - what I remembers: was indeed using sessionStorage at that point, and I traced it to the point where `setItem` was called. Remove weinre, it worked. Add weinre, it breaks. By now this is probably at least 4 FF versions ago, and most likely a weinre version or two has gone by also - so re-testing this issue would be indicated. Good chance it has been resolved by one of the updates....web stuff is moving so friggin fast these days...